# How to get ids when a value is selected in fcbkcomplete? - jsfiddle added

Tags: javascript, jquery, fcbkcomplete

Please go through the below fiddle. I am trying to get the ids of the selected products in the `fcbkcomplete` box and show it as comma separated values in the textbox with `id="interest"`. I wrote a function to achieve that but it didn't work. The function adds the id of the first value and not taking the ids of the other values which are added in the multiple selection box.

http://jsfiddle.net/balac/xDtrZ/1/

I have added `json.txt`. it contains datas like this

```
[{"key":"2", "value":"Canon Powershot "},{"key":"3", "value":"Fastrack Bag"},{"key":"4", "value":"Iphone 4 "},{"key":"5", "value":"Levis Jeans"},{"key":"7", "value":"Indig"},{"key":"8", "value":"Dashing Cars"},{"key":"9", "value":"dsdas"},{"key":"10", "value":"fsfs"}]
```

In the above json value key is the id which I want to display in the textbox as comma separated values. value is the value which will be coming in the dropdown for selection.

while selecting the values in the drop down i want the corresponding key to get added in the textbox as comma separated values.

The problem is that only the key of the first selected item is getting added in the textbox, no matter.

Hope am specific and said all in detail. if anyone want any clarification please ask me i will explain more.

Comment: firebug reported this error: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/balac/xDtrZ/1/show/parseJSON.php?tag=d 404 NOT FOUND 1.14s`  I've never tried using a php script like that in jsFiddle, but I don't that works like that..

Comment: Also, under `Add Resource` you can add URLs to external javascript and CSS files. So I deleted the fcbkcomplete js code that was embedded in your script into an external resource for you. http://jsfiddle.net/xDtrZ/4/

Comment: i know we cant add php file that way..now i changed it to txt file and also the content of txt file is given above

Comment: Check out my answer. I think this solution should work for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a simpler solution for you. Keep in mind, due to the problems I mentioned in my comments I had to drastically simplify your `fcbkcomplete` code to get it working..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
        addontab: true,
        maxitems: 10,
        input_min_size: 0,
        height: 10,
        select_all_text: "select",
        onselect: clicker
    });
});

var clicker = function() {
    var selected = new Array();

    $('option', this).each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('#interest').val(selected.join(', '));
};
```

[See it in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xDtrZ/9/)

**Note:** I had to manually add `<option>'s` to the `select` list to get `fcbkcomplete` to actually work right.  But nevertheless, my logic should work for you regardless.

Also, `fcbkcomplete` apparently dynamically changes the `<option>'s` id to something like `opt_vaQDzJU37ArScs818rc8HUwz9gm1wypP` so I had to use the value instead. There are workarounds for that if you're dead set on using the id instead of the value.

To illustrate my point, modify the loop through each option like this:

```
$('option', this).each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
        var pair = this.attributes[i].name + ': '
            + this.attributes[i].value;
        alert(pair);
    }
    selected.push($(this).val());
});
```

You will see how the attributes end up after `fcbkcomplete` runs.

**Final Edit**

After setting it up on localhost and using a JSON txt file, I was able to finally replicate the problem you were having.  The thing is, the behavior totally changes when you use JSON instead of hard-coding the `<option>`s.  Here is your working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicker = function(e) {
        var selected = new Array();

        // using "this" here was out of context, use #select3
        $('option', $('#select3')).each(function() {
            selected.push(this.value);
        });

        $('#interest').val(selected.join(', '));
    };

    $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
        json_url: "parseJSON.txt",
        addontab: true,
        maxitems: 10,
        input_min_size: 0,
        height: 10,
        select_all_text: "select",
        onselect: clicker
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks but how can i have the keys to get displayed instead of values. in your fiddle, you shown the values added as comma separated and get removed when i remove it from the list.

Comment: As I stated in my edit, the keys appear to be modified automatically by fcbkcomplete..

Comment: Sorry I left the chat because I didn't see you in there and I have to go to sleep soon..

Comment: Hello, so what's up with this? Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: nope i didnt made it yet :(...let me know once you come online for a chat. so, i can explain the problem better....thanks for your help

Comment: As we discussed earlier, you helped me take the values display in the text box as comma separated values. but i want the key to get displayed as comma separated values in the textbox

Comment: Ahh yes, so you haven't made any progress yet? Ok, there is one problem. The `id` attribute **changes** for each option!  The `fcbkcomplete` jquery plugin **_DYNAMICALLY_** changes the `id` attribute for each option when it's loaded. So putting the `id` in the text box is _pointless_.

Comment: nope...not the id in the html field, i meant the key value in json text.       
 Now the value in the json file is getting added as comma separated. but i want to make the key to get added in the text field

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5430/discussion-between-mmmshuddup-and-bala-c)

Comment: [{"key":"2", "value":"Canon Powershot "},{"key":"3", "value":"Fastrack Bag"},{"key":"4", "value":"Iphone 4 "},{"key":"5", "value":"Levis Jeans"},{"key":"7", "value":"Indig"},{"key":"8", "value":"Dashing Cars"},{"key":"9", "value":"dsdas"},{"key":"10", "value":"fsfs"}]

Comment: its working fine so far. but keys which are getting added in the text field as comma separated is not not getting removed when i remove a selected value ...if possible can u pls add that feature in your code ?...

Answer (score 0):

Below link is example of getting value in fcbkcomplete on select. Same process you can do for id to.
https://github.com/emposha/FCBKcomplete/issues/110
example how to use :

```
`//auto complete jquery starts here
     $("#box").fcbkcomplete({
                    width: 250,
                    addontab: true,                   
                    maxitems: 1,
                    input_min_size: 0,
                    height: 10,
                    cache: true,
                    filter_case: true,
                    filter_hide: true,
                    filter_selected: true,
                    newel: true,
                    filter_case:false,
                    onselect: function(item)
                    {
                        getting_value_dealer(item._value, item._id);
                    }
                });
    //auto complete jquery ends here
`
```